# need to find parent child relation in a table using mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have table with below information

```
id  name  level   Parent_id
1   A     1       ---
2   B     1       ----
3   C     2       1
4   D     2       2
5   E     3       3
6   F     3       4
7   G     4       5
8   H     4       5
```

i want the result in this format.

```
id  L1Name   L2 Name  L3 Name  L4Name
1   A        -        -        -
2   B        -        -        -    
3   A        C        -        -
4   B        D        -        -    
5   A        C        E        -
6   B        D        F        -
7   A        C        E        G
8   A        C        E        H
```

i want this result in mysql. we can find this in oracle by using Connect by prior. How about in mysql.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may looking for this

```
     select id , L1Name,   L2Name , L3Name , L4Name
     from (
         select id ,
         if(level =1 , name , '--') L1Name ,
         if(level =2 , name , '--') L2Name ,
         if(level =3 , name , '--') L3Name ,
         if(level =4 , name , '--') L4Name 
         from Table1
         )t
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77d2d/9)

**EDIT :**

try this

```
 SELECT id, L1Name,   L2Name , L3Name , L4Name
 FROM (
     SELECT id,
     IF(id in(1,3,5,7), 'A' , 'B') L1Name ,
     IF(id in(3,5,7) , 'C' , if(id in(1,2), '-', 'D')) L2Name ,
     IF(id in(5,7),'E',if(id in(1,2,3,4), '-', 'F')) L3Name ,
     IF(id =7 , 'G' , if(id in(1,2,3,4,5,6), '-', 'H')) L4Name 
     FROM Table1
 )t
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77d2d/80)

Comment: No it will give result like this..id  L1Name   L2 Name  L3 Name  L4Name
1 A           -        -        -
2       B           -              -        -    
3       -           C              -        -
4       -           D              -        -    
5 -            -              E        -
6 -       -             F        -
7 -       -             -        G
8 -       -             -        H

Please see...